# Application of Lawvere Theories

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, category-theory, topological-groups

This is supposed to be more of a reference request than an actual question, but anyway...

A **Lawvere theory** is a category $\mathcal{T}$ with finite products, st. every object is a power of some distinguished object $X$. The **category of models** is the full subcategory $[\![\mathcal{T},\mathsf{Set}]\!]_\times$ of product preserving functors. Most algebraic categories (like groups, modules, rings etc.) are in fact realized as a category of models of a Lawvere theory. So far so good.

When reading about Lawvere theories it is frequently mentioned that they are special in the sense that they allow us to do algebra in any category $\mathcal{C}$ with finite products, giving a common framework for say *topological groups*, *Lie groups* and *group schemes* etc. Yet I am unable to find any resources on such applications of Lawvere theories beyond the fact that the concept of a $\mathcal{C}$-valued Lawvere theory applies.

I would expect that questions like „under which conditions on $\mathcal{C}$ do colimits exists in the category of models in $\mathcal{C}$? How do we compute them?“ or „how do abelian groups in a *good* category $\mathcal{C}$ compare to ordinary abelian groups? Under which conditions do we have a calculus of short exact sequences? What diagram lemmas hold true in $\mathcal{C}$?“ are already studied in this context, but I could not find a reference.

PS: I guess that by Kelly‘s transfinite constructions internal algebraic constructions on locally presentable categories are monadic, as we can write down a presentation of the monad. Hence in particular the categories of models are monadic and we know how to compute colimits. Yet my question arose from trying to prove things about *topological groups* and *compact Hausdorff groups* and both $\mathsf{Top}$ and $\mathsf{CHaus}$ are far from being locally presentable.

Comment: The questions you are interested in depend a lot more on ambient category than the particular Lawvere theory you are looking at. There isn't that much one can say about the category of Lawvere models in an arbitrary category, just as there isn't much one can say about the category of algebras for an arbitrary monad.

Comment: @ZhenLin Of cause we have to put conditions on $\mathcal{C}$ to get results we can work with. And characterizing such conditions is precisely what I am after. I‘ll edit to make this clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best result I'm aware of is the following:

1. let $T$ be an algebraic theory such that the category of $\sf Set$-models is [protomodular](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/protomodular+category); then the category of models of $T$ in any finitely complete category $\cal E$ is protomodular.
2. If you call "pointed protomodular" an algebraic theory such that its category of $\sf Set$-models is pointed and protomodular, then the category of topological $T$-algebras is [homological](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homological+category), complete and cocomplete. It is, however, almost never a [Barr exact category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exact+category).

Comment: Thank you very much! So I guess reading about protomodular categories is not a bad idea then...

Comment: From my [ill-informed and partial] point of view these two results "motivate" the theory of protomodular categories. I was looking for a condition on the associated monads (for the moment I fail to find it) that would translate into a nice condition in terms of clones, that would translate into...

Comment: There are also results of this type for several subcategories of topological spaces (such as Hausdorff, compact or profinite spaces). https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870804000726, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864105001884

Comment: @ArnaudD. This is perfect. Thank you so much!